# Can auto-mode-alist be used to have Emacs transparently encrypt and decrypt a non .gpg file?

Tags: gpg, encryption, auto-mode-alist

I currently have Emacs encrypting a .gpg file transparently as is the expected behaviour and I'm wondering if this can be extended to all file types so that Emacs can attempt decryption on *all* files without having to use the .gpg extension. I know something like this can be done with org-mode and txt files:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt$" . org-mode))
```

But is there an equivalent for gpg too?

To clarify, I don't mean having to call a file foo.org.gpg to open it in org-mode, rather just foo.org and still encrypt/decrypt it anyway without needing `;; -*- epa-file-encrypt-to: ("name@domain.tld") -*-` either.

Comment: "rather just foo.org" -- are you saying that you intend to have *every org-mode file on your filesystem* encrypted?  You're happy that Emacs will *never* encounter a `*.org` file which is not encrypted?

Comment: @phils Not really, no. I meant that I want Emacs to *check* every file to see if it needs decryption before opening it. Most of my files, whether `*.org` or `*.md` or `*.txt` or `*.tex` (which is pretty much all the types I have), are *not* encrypted, but for those that are, I want to continue using the "proper" extension and still have Emacs check before opening and, if they're not encrypted, do nothing else but open them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but, in case it's not obvious, the requirement is that all files with matching filenames *are* encrypted.

So if you're *really sure* that's what you want, then see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `epa-file-name-regexp`

(n.b. Applied too broadly, this could cause carnage -- you might inadvertently encrypt system-critical files, for instance.  Don't do anything like this without very carefully considering all of the possible ramifications.)

Comment: – Thanks for the answer. I understand from what you're saying that a sort of global "check all .abc files" rule is possible which assumes all .abc files *must* be encrypted. I would like such a global rule but I want Emacs to decrypt encrypted .abc files and simply open the rest if no encryption exists.

Comment: You would need to write a custom file handler which implements that functionality, then, because the one that is used for .gpg files does not work for non-encrypted files (which you can trivially demonstrate by -- *without* using emacs -- giving an unencrypted file a `*.gpg` filename, and then trying to open it with emacs).

Comment: (The one that is used for .gpg files also assumes that you *do* want to encrypt all files with matching filenames whenever you save them.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I work within an Obsidian-style 'vault' so I suppose the possibility of affecting system critical files is close to zero. That said, using the .gpg does not seem like a bad choice if my only alternative is to write a custom file handler.